# Artinian module's socle is essential

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, socle

How do I prove that the [socle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socle_(mathematics)#Socle_of_a_module) of an [Artinian module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artinian_module) is [an essential submodule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_extension)?

I don't see where we should use the artinianity of the module to prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The artinian condition comes in when looking for a minimal submodule. Let $H \neq 0$ be a submodule such that $$H \cap {Soc}(N) = 0.$$ Then we wish to find a minimal submodule of $N$ contained in $H$. This is given by the artinian condition on $N$. But this minimal submodule should be contained in $Soc(N)$, by definition. Contradiction.

Comment: @A._Van_Antwerpen can you correct the typo ($N$ instead of $soc(N)$,

Comment: Thanks! Didn't notice the typo.

Comment: More simply: let $H$ be a nonzero submodule. Then $H$ has a simple submodule.